# Create Pivot Table using multiple date columns of Recycling Bin

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, pivot-table, powerquery

Lets make an example of a situation :  I have the Recycle bin on Windows where there are multiple date columns that represent different attributes : creation date / last modification date / deletion date.

Now lets modify this typicall example and suppose that in this directory we have both files that have been deleted and others that have not those that have not been deleted have a null value in the correspondent row of the deletion date column.

***Given this case I'm trying to create a pivot table that in the first column displays the ratio of deleted files over created files for a given month.***

[image: .]

Comment: What's your problem? I read your post where you describe some situations, but that's about it. What kind of difficulty have you come across, what do you need help with.

Comment: Your Question is just a question, it does not show any effort on your part to solve the problem or show what you have tried and are stuck. StackOverflow is not a site to get free solutions, it is a community to help each other find solutions. If you are stuck on HOW to get the data of the files, please update your question with that and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate table with all the dates used in the principal table. Create a relationship using using Power BI / Power Query / Power Pivot ( I used Power Pivot ) between each of the 3 columns and the separate date table (2 of those columns should be inactive by deselecting the checkbox at the bottom left side of the dialogue box when creating said relationship). Then create a measure using this formula

```
=DIVIDE(CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1[deleted]);USERELATIONSHIP(Table1[deleted];Table2[dates]));[Count of created])
```